# Hello, I created a function that finds the max of three numbers using arrow function in JavaScript. Is the code ok?

Tags: if-statement, arrow-functions

I tried using if-else statements inside the arrow function and it runs fine. I was wondering if it the code was correct.

```
const fu= (x,y,z) => {
    if(x>y){
        if(x>z)return x;
        else return z;
    }
    else return y;
}
console.log(fu(10,14,9));
```

Comment: Why are you wondering? Did you try it? Did it _work_? If so then what does "ok" or "correct" mean?

Comment: What’s wrong with `Math.max`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the case [2,19,40], it'll return 19 instead of 40 because the code it'll not verify the third number since x > y is not true.

I believe the better approach should be receiving the numbers as an vector and iterating over them asking if the previous one is greater then the current. Something like this:

```
const fu2 = (a) => {
  let greater = a[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] > greater) greater = a[i];
  }
    
  return greater;
}
```

Or if you don't want to use loop, check if y is greater than z before return it.